# I can import cv2 in python interactive shell, but it says no module named cv2 if I run python script

Tags: python, opencv

When I import cv2 in python interactive shell:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.__version__
2.4.8
>>>
```

But when I run this code:

```
import cv2
print (cv2.__version__)
```

It has an error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 as cv
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Is it possible that you're running `test.py` using python3 instead of python2?

Comment: @EliSadoff Solved it. I used cloud9 IDE. If I use python test.py it works well. But if I click 'run' button it failed. Thank you very much.